# How to continue script commands, functions & variables after chroot?

Tags: bash, shell-script, arch-linux, system-installation, chroot

I have written a BASH script that would prepare and install everything during ArchLinux initial installation. The script would work fine and execute everything successfully until it reaches the `arch-chroot` command then it would stop.

Also, the solutions I found online (like the `EOF` trick) wouldn't pass functions or variables after `chroot`.

Here is a demo:

```
#!/bin/bash

username=test
pause_var=1

pause ()
{
if [ $pause_var -eq 1 ]
then
    read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to continue"
fi
}

arch-chroot /mnt #the script stops after executing this line!!

# some commands after chroot
useradd -m $username
pause

echo $username:123 | chpasswd
pause

# ... more commands below
```

I googled for a solution but none of the solutions that I found have worked for me. I'm a Linux noob.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man arch-chroot`

`arch-chroot [options] chroot-dir [command]`

So you can simply do this `arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash /file/in/chroot/script.sh`

If it doesn't accept additional arguments you could try `arch-chroot /mnt /file/in/chroot/script.sh`